# How to profile unit tests with MSTest using dotTrace 4.0, ReSharper 5.1 and VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mstest, dottrace

I am trying to profile a single unit test (the test itself passes) using dotTrace 4.0.
It seems that dotTrace profiles Resharper's test runner instead of profiling the test itself.

I could find an answer from JetBrains dev team regarding this issue with dotTrace 3.1:
it seems that MSTest creates a new process for running tests, and it was a known limitation of dotTrace 3.1 that it could not handle this behaviour.

This behaviour of MSTest can be inhibited using the /noisolation option in command line, but it cannot be done from within the IDE.

This page here:
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/NetProf/Profiling+Unit+tests+with+dotTrace+4.0
also tells me that using dotTrace 4.0 and ReSharper 5.0, it should work out-of-the box.

Which it does not.

So I tried to run the test from the standalone UI of dotTrace as explained in the above link, it actually does the trick but with limitations:

- the described method runs all tests within a specified dll. The arguments used to launch the test could maybe be tuned to run one specific test, but it seems a lot of trouble for running just one tiny UT.
- it seems all my source code is not attached to the session, which takes some more time to correct.

I went through VS options, ReSharper options, .testrunconfig options, without any luck.
Anyone has solved this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there was an option in ReSharper that I had not seen: ReSharper > Options > Tools > Unit Testing > MSTest > Use this Test Run Configuration
When I set this to default it runs just fine.

Something is wrong in my test configuration after all. I do not know what is wrong, since the only difference with default is that I have Deployment enabled with a few XML files that are used for a test project I am not using right now. And I do not understand either how that relates with my problem.

Anyway, since it works like this...

Comment: What? its asking for a Test Setting file... what do i do?

Comment: @Seabizkit you should probably create a new question with more details to what your problem is, there is a lot of information missing in your question!

Comment: Just posted a new question along the same lines... yeah get your point. very new to dottrace and was trying to find out the correct way to profile a MSTest... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44694925/dot-trace-profile-why-is-my-in-memory-fetch-being-flagged-as-slow

Answer (score 0):

This might have been caused by built-in code coverage which comes with Visual Studio. Please make sure it's turned off for your solution.

WBR, Oleg Stepanov
JetBrains s.r.o.
"Develop with pleasure!"

Comment: I thought about that but I have VS Pro, which I do not think ships with the code coverage tools.